# Verify browser requirements and settings

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, zend-framework

I need to verify if a browser meets the requirements of our website. If one of the requirements is not met, I'd like to display a corresponding warning on the login page. The requirements are the following:

- Cookies must be enabled
- Javascript must be enabled
- HTML5 must be supported
- IE9+

What's your approach to this problem? Can you e.g. recommend an open source library (Javascript, PHP, Zend Framework 2) I can use to do the job? Or is there a good diagnostics website I can refer to for checking browser requirements? Verifying the requirements will save us a lot of support time.

Comment: what's *your* approach? you have said what you want, not what you have done to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like http://detector.dmolsen.com/ could be of great help. It can be combined with the well known http://modernizr.com/ too!

Answer (score 0):

- you can check if 1st party cookies are enabled by setting and reading a cookie from javascript. You can do the same with 3rd party cookies by doing an ajax request to a php file
- its a tough one
- you can't detect if "html5" is supported but you can detect if certain javascript functions are enabled (http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html)
- if you are using jQuery you can go with 
  if (jQuery.browser && jQuery.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version > 9)

unfortunately the latter doesn't work with jQuery version > 1.9.1